# Accessing other class attribute PyQT6

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt6

I want to access `MainWindow.blocks` when `Preview` is being initialized. The code is as follows

```py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QListWidget, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QFrame, QGridLayout, \
    QPlainTextEdit

from general.main import GeneralModule


# noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set-up MainWindow
        self.setWindowTitle("ORCAgui")
        self.mainwindow_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        # Add Preview
        self.preview = Preview(self)
        self.mainwindow_layout.addWidget(self.preview)

        # Setup Main Window view (QWidget)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.mainwindow_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.blocks = {
            'runtype': '',
            'method': '',
            'basis_set': '',
            'basis_block': '',
            'charge': '0',
            'multiplicity': '1',
            'coords': '',
        }

        self.show()

class Preview(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Set-up layout
        self.preview_layout = QGridLayout()
```

Someone adviced me to use `self.parent().property`  but doesnt work.

When I run `print(self.parent.block)` the results is  `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'blocks'`.

Moreover, running just `print(self.parent)` yields `<built-in method parent of Preview object at 0x10bf3bca0>`

Inserting  `help(self.parent)` into `def __init__(self, parent):` of `Preview` yields:

```
Help on built-in function parent:

parent(...) method of __main__.Preview instance
    parent(self) -> QObject
```

Using `self.parent().blocks` results in `AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'blocks'` and `self.parent().preview` results in AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'preview'

Comment: It's not really clear why or what you want to do that but, since you need it for `Preview`, have you simply tried to move `self.blocks = ...` *before* `self.preview = Preview(self)`?

Comment: And that was the solution! Simple yet so effective. Thank you! One more question - do you think it copies them or just pass as reference?